# Can't click on a button on booking.com with Selenium & Python

Tags: python-3.x, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

I am scraping a website booking.com to test Selenium. I got some code from this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j7VZsCCnptM). I got stuck to click on a button to work (The currency button or language button on the top of the home page). I tried a couple of CSS selectors and could not make the button clicked. Any help is appreciated.
Omar

```
# run.py

from booking.booking import Booking
with Booking() as bot:
    print('before land_first_page from run.py')
    bot.land_first_page(teardown=True)
    print('after land_first_page from run.py')
    bot.change_currency()


#########################
# booking.py

import os
import booking.constants as const
from selenium import webdriver

class Booking(webdriver.Chrome):
    def __init__(self, driver_path=const.chromePath, teardown=True):
        self.driver_path = driver_path
        self.teardown = teardown
        os.environ['PATH'] += self.driver_path
        super(Booking, self).__init__()
        self.implicitly_wait(15)
        self.maximize_window()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        while(self.teardown):
            pass  # i.e. do nothing until teardown is False
        if self.teardown:
            self.quit()

    def land_first_page(self, teardown):
        self.get(const.BASE_URL)

    def change_currency(self, currency=None):
        print('change_currency')
        # data-testid="header-currency-picker-trigger"
        currency_element = self.find_element_by_css_selector(
            'button[data-testid="header-currency-picker-trigger"]')
        print('currency_element: ', currency_element)
        currency_element.click()

    def change_language(self, language=None):
        language_element = self.find_element_by_css_selector(
            'button[data-tooltip-text="Choose your language"]')

        language_element.click()
```

I tried several CSS selectors but could not click on the currency button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm experiencing the same issue, but I found the solution that works for me. The idea is to use driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button id') to find all buttons that represent the currency, checking them one-by-one if it is matching against the currency as input the parameter. If so, button.click(). If not found, use "USD" as default currency. Please find code below.

```
def change_currency(self, currency=None):
  currency_element = self.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-testid="header-currency-picker-trigger"]')
  currency_element.click()
  is_currency_found = False
  default_currency = 'USD'
  btn_default_currency = None
  btns = self.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-testid="selection-item"]')
  for btn in btns:
    currency_value = btn.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.ea1163d21f').text
```

> This is the div that displays the button currency.

```
    if currency_value == default_currency:
      btn_default_currency = btn
    if currency_value == currency:
      btn.click()
      is_currency_found = True
      break

  if not is_currency_found:
    print("No matching currency found, USD is used as default currency")
    btn_default_currency.click()
```